# {{ auth()->user()->email }} / {{ Auth::user()->email }} not working in x-component

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-fortify

`php artisan make:component Navbar`, created:

- `App\View\Components\Navbar.php`
- `app\resources\views\components\navbar.blade.php`

Placing `{{ auth()->user()->email }}` or `{{ Auth::user()->email }}` in the blade file, gave this error:

- `Trying to get property 'email' of non-object`.

Tried to fix this by changing my `App\View\Components\Navbar.php` to:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Navbar extends Component
{
    public $email;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($email = null)
    {
        $this->email = 'info@example.com';
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.navbar');
    }
}
```

And added `{{ $email }}` to my blade file and it worked.

However, I want to display the e-mail address from the authenticated user, so I changed `App\View\Components\Navbar.php` to:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Navbar extends Component
{
    public $email;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($email = null)
    {
        $this->email = Auth::user()->email;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.navbar');
    }
}
```

And I got the same error again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're having because the user is not authenticated. Maybe add a check before calling the component in the blade file, wrap the component between @auth directive. Something like this

```php
@auth
    <x-navbar></x-navbar>
@endauth
```